# Appending tuples to a Pandas dataframe and "cannot concatenate" - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, tuples, typeerror

I want to fill up a dataframe from a scraping loop. Say I created an empty DF with four columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

Then the loop to fill it looks like this:

```
for i in range:
  a = x['col1'][i]
  b = x['col2'][i]
  c = x['col3'][i]
  d = x['col4'][i]
  tup = (a,b,c,d)
  df = df.append(tup)
```

This is the error I get, though:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add dictionary instead of tuple:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

for i in range(10):
    a = i + 1
    b = i + 2
    c = i + 3
    d = i + 4
    d = {"A": a, "B": b, "C": c, "D": d}
    df = df.append(d, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4   5
2   3   4   5   6
3   4   5   6   7
4   5   6   7   8
5   6   7   8   9
6   7   8   9  10
7   8   9  10  11
8   9  10  11  12
9  10  11  12  13
```

**But** using `.append` like this is anti-pattern. You should see `FutureWarning` that this method will be removed in future version of pandas.

Instead, create dataframe in one go and skip creating empty dataframe at the beginning:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [{"A": i + 1, "B": i + 2, "C": i + 3, "D": i + 4} for i in range(10)]
)
```

Comment: How do I loop over two iterators? My try:

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [{{"data": RS_let['Data Fato'][i], "hora": RS_let['Hora Fato'][i], "grupo": RS_let['Grupo Fato'][i], 
       "enquadramento": RS_let['Tipo Fato'][i], "municipio": RS_let['Municipio Fato'][i], "local":RS_let['Local Fato'][i],
       "bairro": RS_let['Bairro'][i], "ordem_vitima": j+1, "vitima_idade": RS_let.iloc[i,(9+(j*3)+1)].astype(int),
       "vitima_sexo": RS_let.iloc[i,(9+(j*3)+2)], "vitima_cor": RS_let.iloc[i,(9+(j*3)+3)]} 
      for j in range(RS_let['Quantidade Vítimas'][i])} 
     for i in range(len(RS_let))]
)